# Adding multiple answers to "Tips for golfing in [Language]" questions

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

I've been lurking in this community for quite a while and finally want to start participating and golfing.  I'm mostly an iOS developer so I expect to golf in Swift and Objective-C.  I recently added an answer to [Tips for golfing in Swift](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79203/19617) and I am wondering what the educate is for answering these types of questions.

If I have multiple tips, should I aggregate them into a single answer or spread them across multiple answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard is one tip per answer. If you look at the existing tips questions (like [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/45941)), you'll see that they specifically state this.

Comment: Thanks.  Not every tip question states this, so I wanted to make sure.  Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @JAL It's more of a precedent than a policy. It makes it easier to vote up good tips and vote down bad tips. If a good tip and a bad tip were in the same answer, how would you vote?

Comment: Note that what counts as "one tip" is a bit of a judgment call. Some tips include multiple ways to deal with a situation or multiple ways a trick can be used.